# how to apply a function on child element using $(this) in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am basically trying to apply slide down navigation in jQuery.
I use this code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu").hover(function(){
            $(".submenu").animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 'slow');
        }, function(){
            $(".submenu").animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 'slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I hover upon a `.menu` div then all the `.submenu` div gets slide down. So I tried to accomplish it using `$(this)` . But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please post the HTML that this applies to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` as a context to search for the `.submenu` element within, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").hover(function(){
        $(".submenu", this).animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 'slow');
    }, function(){
        $(".submenu", this).animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you want to bind events like this :

```
   $(document.body).on({
       mouseover : function(e) {
             $(this).find(".submenu")...
         },
       mouseout  : function (e) {
            //...
          }
       //,...
     },".menu");
```

Comment: While this is true when adding disparate events, `hover` will do this for you already.

Comment: but it does eat up more memory than delegating + elements cannot be appended dynamically